# Excel VBA to Excel decimal precision

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a VBA script that generates allocations that need to be precise out to 20 decimal places. I use `CDec()` to fill the array with the proper decimal precision. The issue I have is that when I output the array to an Excel worksheet, the decimal precision drops significantly. For instance, I confirmed that in my array, the number is `0.1557094848581301243552712433`, but when it is output into the worksheet, it drops to `0.15570948485813`. I can write the array to a text file and further confirm the array holds the correct level of precision. I have even tried creating a pipe delimited text file and doing `TextToColumns` to no avail.

Does anyone know how to maintain a higher level of decimal precision when bringing numbers into excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put: Excel only supports 15 digit precision "when displaying". MSFT KB reference below.  Oddly it stores the correct value, it just can't (or doesn't) represent it.

**Work arounds**

- Certain addins may help (See References)
- Store the value as Text.  which has no such limit but no math or rounding may occur

**References:**

- [MSFT KB](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269370)
- [MSFT Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/when-i-am-entering-16-digit-number-in-excel-its/7f50828d-77b4-4ad2-8ea7-0411d0236bd0?auth=1)
- [Sister Stack Site w/ similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/373997/adding-more-than-15-digits-in-excel)